# Can i declare a method in an interface only in development?

Tags: ios

Can i declare a method in an interface only in development?

If in an interface

```
@interface TestClass : NSObject

#if DEVELOPMENT
-(void)doStuffOnlyInDevelopment;
#endif

@end
```

Would this work?

I have tried this with no build errors yet the autocomplete does not resolve this method when i run it in unit tests. DEVELOPMENT is declared as well.

How else could i achieve this result?

Essentially making an method in the interface of a class only visible in certain cases?

Answer (score 0):

While what you have above does work, Xcode's autocomplete does get confused when you do this. I would also advise against using preprocessor directives to remove method declarations.  Instead, in the body of the methods use the preprocessor directives to make them a no-op if you are not in development mode.

```
-(void)doStuffOnlyInDevelopment {
#if DEVELOPMENT
    //Development only code here
#endif
}
```

This will mean the following:

1. Autocomplete should be able to figure it out
2. Your code will actually compile for release without removing calls to this method or preprocessor directives around the code where you call them